# telegram link preview shows login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, telegram

I have a website implemented by Laravel 5

I don't have any problems with telegram link preview itself.

Some of my pages are behind authentication which means users need to login to access those pages.

The problem is, when I put one of those links(that required login) on telegram, it shows the preview for the login page instead of the intended URL. It is completely understandable and expected but I don't know how to solve it.

My first guess was that telegram uses a bot to do this but apparently it does not.
I also tried working with user agent but I realized that the user agent it uses for this job is the same as browsers.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe meta tags? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: what do you by meta tags?

Comment: Does that page required login?

Comment: Yes, actually that is exactly the problem

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/). Here is demo tags:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
  <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

You can provide your own image (screenshot of the page or something else) in `og:image` tag, and telegram will use it as thumb image.

**UPDATE**

You can detect telegram webpage preview bot by its user-agent: `TelegramBot (like TwitterBot)`. To make sure that Telegram does really use this user-agent you can ask [webpagebot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot) to fetch preview for the url you get from [webhook testing](https://webhook.site/) service and check received headers:

[image]

[image]

But I strongly recommend you not to expose sensitive information to this user-agent because anyone can fake preview bot's requests.

Comment: Thank you so much . I have set these meta tags . As I have mentioned the problem is the login thing

Answer (score 0):

> My first guess was that telegram uses a bot to do this but apparently it does not.

Actually, it does! The bot will appear in your logs with the user agent `TelegramBot (like TwitterBot)`. The ones I've seen came from the network range 149.154.164.0/22.

That all being said, there isn't going to be any good way to let Telegram see the contents of a page that won't risk exposing that content to normal users (either directly, or by pasting private URLs into a Telegram client). Your best bet will be to use an appropriate title on your login page.

Comment: I had found this bot as well. But apparently for this job telegram does not use this. 
Because I use a package in my Laravel application to work with bots (like googlebot, bingbot ,etc) . Shockingly the code I have used does not recognize telegram as a bot!! 
here is the package I have used for this: https://github.com/jenssegers/agent